# Resizing slider images in a Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Can someone tell me, by examining source code of this wordpress theme ifthe slider images is resizable or not ?

http://pixelthemes.net/?theme=immersion

Answer (score 0):

off course it is possible. you can use the below script to make it resizable:

https://github.com/filamentgroup/Responsive-Images

Comment: Going to implement that and i will be back